# Query para ordenar por duas datas Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho a minha tabela `tbl_noticias` com duas datas do tipo `date`: `data_criacao_noticia` e `data_atualizada_noticia`.

O objectivo é a listagem seja ordenada do seguinte modo:

- se a `data_atualizada_noticia` for diferente de 0000-00-00 e maior que a `data_criacao_noticia` deverá aparecer primeiro, ou seja a data mais recente aparece sempre primeiro.

Na imagem seguinte fica o exemplo do que estou a tentar:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou a usar php e mysql para fazer a consulta. É possível usar operadores ternários na consulta ou algo do genero?

Comment: Pode ordenar por código ou precisa ser na consulta?

Comment: Tem que ser na consulta se possível @DanielGregatto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Experimenta este SQL

```
SELECT n.*,
(IF (n.data_atualizacao > n.data_criacao, n.data_atualizacao , n.data_criacao)) as data_maior
 FROM tbl_noticias n
 ORDER BY data_maior DESC
```

Comment: Era mesmo isso, obrigado @DanielGregatto